# How to inherit External Maven POM in Project POM

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, maven

I'm looking at the Google Web Toolkit pom file at http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/docs/maven-googlewebtoolkit2-plugin/examples.html and it doesn't seem right to copy all of it into my project pom, as it would add too much unnecessary clutter.

Hence, am looking for a way I could store the GWT pom in an external file, and make reference to it in my project pom.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That project is deprecated, use [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) from codehaus.

> Hence, am looking for a way I could store the GWT pom in an external
>   file, and make reference to it in my project pom.

That's [multi-module-project](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/project.html#Multi-project_setup) setup, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the gwt Pom as the parent Pom for your project?
Something like this in your pom.xml?

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.totsp.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-gwt-sample-withouthome</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: no i haven't tried this. but it seems too complicated, and i might just ditch the idea of playing with it for the time being.